# Rhinocommon lock layer

Tags: c#, rhinoceros

I am trying to avoid that a user locks a layer in a Rhino plugin written using Rhinocommon. When the plugin is initialized, an event handler is coupled to the LayerTableEvent using

```
RhinoDoc.LayerTableEvent += this.OnLayerEvent;
```

The event handler is defined as

```
public void OnLayerEvent(object sender, Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTableEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState.IsLocked)
    {
        e.Document.Layers[e.LayerIndex].IsLocked = false;
        e.Document.Layers[e.LayerIndex].CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

The event is triggered when a lock in the Rhino layers panel is clicked and the `if` condition evaluates to `true` if the layer gets locked (a breakpoint inside the `if` statement is reached). However, after the event, the layer remains locked. Is it possible that `e.Document.Layers[e.LayerIndex].IsLocked = false;` does not lock a layer. Or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is slightly misleading regarding setting the locked state of a layer.  In your case for Rhino 5 you will need to create a new layer and modify the layer table.  I have not tested your code exactly, but I have tested the general method to create a new `Rhino.DocObjects.Layer` and use this to Modify the layer table.  Here is how this would look like in your code:

```
public void OnLayerEvent(object sender, Rhino.DocObjects.Tables.LayerTableEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState.IsLocked)
    {
        var newLayerSettings = new Rhino.DocObjects.Layer();
        newLayerSettings.Name = e.Document.Layers[e.LayerIndex].Name;
        newLayerSettings.IsVisible = true;
        e.Document.Layers.Modify(newLayerSettings, e.LayerIndex, true);
    }
}
```

The procedure to do this has changed for the next version of Rhino to be more like your original example.  You can test this in the RhinoWIP if you have a valid Rhino 5 license.

As a last suggestion, you can also ask your question on https://discourse.mcneel.com/c/rhino-developer where you might get more a bit more traffic and probably a faster response to your queries.